# django, how to get object from get_or_create and use it to other get_or_create?

Tags: django

CODE example:

```
keyword = Keyword.objects.get_or_create(text=text)

sub_keyword = SubKeyword.objects.get_or_create(keyword=keyword, user=request.user)
```

It returns: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Keyword'`

from line: `sub_keyword = SubKeyword.objects.get_or_create(keyword=keyword, user=request.user)`

How to do it?

Comment: keyword=keyword.id

Comment: @a_k_v It says: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
keyword, created = Keyword.objects.get_or_create(text=text)

sub_keyword, created = SubKeyword.objects.get_or_create(keyword=keyword.id, user=request.user)
```

`get_or_create` returns tuple like `(object, created)`. That's why you have AttributeError. See [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) docs